# How to model "hasMany" in NoSQL for near real time query?

Tags: indexing, view, relationship, couchbase

I've been playing with Couchbase and I'm trying to find best ways to model relationships.

**belongsTo**: this is fairly easy. When I have **Posts** and **Comments**, I can have the following structure in comments.

```
Comment:
    id: 1
    parent: this is where I store an id of post
```

**hasMany**: This seemed pretty easy at first. Assuming I have **Posts** and **Users** and users can like a Post, I had the following structure.

```
Posts:
    id: 1
    likedBy: [
        'user-id-1',
        'user-id-2'
    ]
```

This works if I have may be...a thousand likes, but as the # of likes increases..it gets slower and slower and I have to lock the document.

My first solution was using **view**, but then view is not real time even though it is adequate for most of queries. There is always delay for indexing.

Then I thought about using a **relational database** just to save relationship and I think this might be pretty good choice, but I would like to know if there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

For the comments I might use something like [this](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/july/advanced-object-modeling-for-high-write-rates-with-logging-and-event-data), but instead of "SomeEventType" and date time stamp like it has in the blog post, I would do the ID of the post itself. This way you get the counter object for that post, which gives you the upper bound of the array of comments. Then you can iterate through that list, use pagination or do a bulk get for all of them. Since this would be interacting purely with the Data Service, it would meet your consistency and real time needs.

For the number of likes, you could use a counter object. For recording which user's like a post or comment, you could store that in a separate object or maybe have an index object like you have in your question per user? Let me think more about this one.

Comment: I've thought about counter, but it still does not solve the problem since users can delete a comment. It can work as a workaround, but I can't say it's a best way of doing it.

Even for likes...it has to track of user ids, not only # of likes. View can work, but it's not real time.